# Every import in parent script slows down multiprocessing initialization?

Tags: python, import, queue, multiprocessing, delay

I am currently using the python multiprocessing package and stumbled accross a weird issue (working with windows 10, python 3.6).
A module I wrote and use in a script initializes multiprocessing, but somehow there is a big delay until the other cores start to work.

It turns out that the more I import in the script the longer the first core needs to start working. The weirdest thing about it is that the module I imported cannot see the other imports...

It is a little hard to explain, just have a look at the two dummy scripts below (even only one core is used for multiprocessing there!). If I import numpy and pandas in the first script, the queue in the second script returns with a delay of 1s. If I do not import these packages, the delay is only 0.15s.
It does not matter what I import in the first script, the delay increases gradually.

I could not find any similar issue in Stack overflow and would be super happy if someone could help me fix that problem.

I already tried this code on an AWS server (Server 2012) - same issue.

First script

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from testmultiprocessing2 import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
   tryit()
```

Second script

```
from multiprocessing import Process,  Queue
import time


def scanner(t,output_queue):
   output_queue.put(time.time()-t)

def tryit():
   output_queue = Queue()
   t=time.time()
   pr = Process(target=scanner, args=(t,output_queue))#input_queue,output_queue,debugging_queue))
   pr.start()
   pr.join()
   print(output_queue.get())
```

Comment: Have you tried timing how long the imports take?

Comment: I did some tests and I think the delay could be about twice the time the imports take